# Windows 7 and TOR no longer working.

Tags: bridge

The last time I used TOR was a couple of months ago.  I did nothing to the computer(s) it's on.  TOR now shows the Loading Progress Bar and Gets about half way loaded and Stops.  Is anyone Else having this problem?  Windows 7 setup.

Comment: Could you click "Copy Tor Log To Clipboard" and add the logs to your question, please?